# How to set visible a JButton depending the user that logs in?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, netbeans, jbutton

I'm doing a proyect where I have two frames, the first one is the login frame where users can type the username and password, the second frame have many JButton that the user will see after the login.

The thing is, I want to have like two roles, users#1 will be able to see all the JButtons while the user#2 will be able to see just a few of them.

I tried to do some research but I don't find topics related to this.

I already connected my login frame to the database and the users can be validated already if they exists or not, I just need to SetVisible the JButtons of the second frame depending of the user that logs in.

I hope I was able to explain my question well, as English is not my first language.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in the database table have an additional boolean field (or an integer security level field) that can be set as to who see's what buttons. When the User logs in, this field is also read. It's then just a matter of setting who see's what:

```
If (userSeeAll) { ..... }
else { ..... }
```

**or**

```
switch (userLevel) {
    case 0:
        // User see'e no buttons
        break;
    case 1:
        // User see's two buttons
        break;
    case 2:
        // User see's 5 buttons
        break;
    case 3:
        // User see's 10 buttons
        break;
    ..... etc ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have an integer field so my system can read it, but the thing is I don't know how to set that from the login frame so it I can deactivate the JButton in the next frame.

Can I set a JButton to set visible to false from the login frame? Is there a way to do that?